# Vue yarn build is using cached version

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, yarnpkg

I am using ***VueJS and Yarn***.

### Problem is:

I was running `yarn build` AND `npm run build` but both create a `dist` folder with an old version of my code!

First time I face this problem.

### What I have tried and checked:

- I have tried to clear browser caching.
- Tried to open from totally different device.
- Run `yarn cache clean` and `npm cache clean`

But nothing worked! I always get an old version of code which I don't even know how!

### Also I get this message while building saying:

`asset size limit: The following asset(s) exceed the recommended size limit (244 KiB).`

## EDIT:

I have fixed the ***asset size limit*** but still got the same problem!

`yarn build` compile a different old version than that `yarn serve`!

Comment: Try put "devtool: false" in webpack.js file, should fix your asset size limit

Comment: Did you remove `dist` folder after each build? Did you generate your files with some random hash, if yes, the hash is the same or different?

Comment: @Elad tried but nothing changed

Comment: @VladyslavBabenko yes I have tried removing it but nothing changed.. Also tried it on difference device.. And no I don't use any hash.. I just run `yarn build`

Comment: Have you used both yarn and npm on one project? Do you have both package-lock.json and yarn.lock in your project?